# 2D JSON String Array Deserialized into JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I have a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{"2000":["1", "2", "3"],"2001":["1", "2", "3"],"2002":["1", "2", "3"]}
```

The string above comes from the "backend" and my JavaScript function receives the JSON string as a parameter, which is called backendData.

Looping through the parameter as below, gives the following result.

```
for (key in backendData) {
    alert(key);
}
```

Three alertboxes with the values: 2000, 2001 and 2002.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to access the string array for each of the "parent" elements. Using syntax `key[0]` etc. gives me the character at index 0 in the string which in all three cases are "2".

Help needed.

/Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loops over all the values.  Remember backendData is just a javascript object.

```
for (key in backendData) {
   for (x in backendData[key])
    alert(backendData[key][x]);
}
```

or in your example data this would work

```
for (key in backendData) {
   alert(backendData[key][0];
   alert(backendData[key][1];
   alert(backendData[key][2];
}
```

Comment: Well gor me somewhat further, although the inner loop gives me the index position and not the actual value, so I get 0, 1 and 2 in the inner loop alert box values.

Comment: OK the alert in your inner loop should be backendData[key][x] instead of just x as x is aparently just the index. Confused me but lead me to the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
backendData[key]
```

since you want to look up a mapping within the *backendData* map.  `key[0]` indexes something *inside of `key`* (as a character array), which isn't what you're after as you discovered.

Comment: Great gow me 1 step further returns the string for the key as 1,2,3 how do I parse that into an array ?